# How to set an image as a background for a container when using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, containers

I am trying to set an image (.jpg) as the background for half of my page which is one of the containers. I can set a background as a solid color, but when I go to set it as an image, something doesn't work and it goes back to white. Below is my CSS..

```
.container {
background-image: url("background-image.jpg");
}
```

The html is quite lengthy so I will leave that out. Note that I am using bootstrap to make the webpage resize responsively. Thanks!

Comment: the image not in any folder? also try ... url("../background-image.jpg") see if it help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the background-size property and set it to contain, this will place an image inside of the element containing the class.  Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/p9oak4b7/1/

```
    .container {
   background-image: url("background-image.jpg");
   background-size: contain;
   }
```

EDIT :

Add this class to your stylesheet , and add it to the container, here is an example with containter-fluid https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CMOf.jpg

```
    .image {
   background-image: url("background-image.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   }
```

Comment: What if my container is actually a .container-fluid?

Comment: Instead of background-size: contain; try with background-size: cover;

Comment: @CodyDeBos check out my edit that should fix your problem.